# Connecting Processmaker 3.2 (bitnami installer) to sql server

Tags: sql, connect, processmaker

How can I connect processmaker 3 to sql server database ?

It seems that mssql functions family deprecated from php but codes of processmaker did not updated yet !

what i did until now is explained [here](https://forum.processmaker.com/viewtopic.php?f=40&t=709734&p=793643#p793166)

Comment: Did you try [this](http://wiki.processmaker.com/3.0/Database_Connections) method? If yes, update your question with what you have tried so far.

Comment: Yes I tried that and test connection was successful but when I create a form and -for example- try to fill a dropdown with a query from mssql datasource I got this error in preview (and also in output) "An internal error occurred #{errorNumber}. Please contact your system administrator for more information."

Comment: So your "question" is actually answered, and now you got a new problem?

Comment: "Actually" I send a post to processmaker forum and after weeks have find a way to figure it out myself. And I wonder if that can help anyone else.
So if qustioning and accepting answers of mine , is illegal or reputation eater (!) in stackoverflow please notice me to delete my question.
I am newbie at stackoverflow !

Comment: It is perfectly fine and encouraged by the SO policy. I thought that your comment from yesterday would introduce a new problem, my bad. Well done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution !
And since we owe to "open source" :) I posted an [answer](https://forum.processmaker.com/viewtopic.php?f=40&t=709734&p=793643#p793643) to processmaker forum

Best wishes !